# QML - Mask item color with background color

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to reproduce the behavior of the Android timer picker control where, as is possible to see in the picture, the time number change the color (from black to white) when the handle is over it (also partially). Someone know if is possible to get the same using QML and, in case, how?

[image]

Comment: what Qt version do you use?

Comment: I'd argue that the text is really hard to read when the color changes like that. But one way to achieve it would be to draw the text in both black and white at the same time, but put the white text within an OpacityMask using the circle image as the mask source.That way the white only shows when it overlaps the circle.

Comment: @folibis The latest 6.6.0

Comment: @JarMan I'm thinking the same solution too but I asked here to know if there is an easier way to do it...

Comment: @JarMan, There is no `Opacity Mask` in Qt 6, just as there is no `QtGraphicalEffects` at all. So you should either downgrade to Qt 5 or use `Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects` instead. I do not know why, but they turned a great tool into something useless. , As for me, I moved all my new projects to Flutter.

Comment: @folibis They simply moved all the GraphicalEffects features in a separated module with some nice additions. The problem is this new module is under commercial and GPL license only, no LGPL supported and this is a very bed news.

Comment: There have been people trying to port QtGraphicalEffects to Qt6, like https://github.com/moodyhunter/QtGraphicalEffects, but in the end you could try to write your own shader

Answer (score 1):

As other's have indicated you can use `Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects` if you define two versions of the numbers, e.g. a "black" version and a "red" version you can use an `OpacityMask` to draw the "red" version ontop of the "black" version but only in the areas that satisfy the `OpacityMask`. In this case, the `OpacityMask` is set to the `red` circle:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Shapes
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects
Page {
    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 200
        height: width
        color: "#ddd"
        radius: width / 2
        OutlineText {
            x: 20
            y: 110
            text: "41"
            font.pointSize: 10
        }
        OutlineText {
            x: 45
            y: 150
            text: "35"
            font.pointSize: 10
            font.bold: true
        }
        Item {
            id: circleMask
            anchors.fill: parent
            Rectangle {
                x: 20
                y: 115
                width: 25
                height: width
                color: "red"
                radius: width / 2
            }
        }
        Item {
            id: overlay
            anchors.fill: parent
            visible: false
            OutlineText {
                x: 20
                y: 110
                text: "41"
                color: "red"
                font.pointSize: 10
            }
        }
        Shape {
            ShapePath {
                strokeColor: "red"
                strokeWidth: 4
                startX: 100; startY: 100
                PathLine { x: 30; y: 130 }
            }
        }
        OpacityMask {
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: overlay
            maskSource: circleMask
        }
    }
}

// OutlineText.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Label {
    color: "black"
    property color outlineColor: "white"
    Repeater {
        model: 9
        Label {
            x: index % 3 - 1
            y: Math.floor(index / 3) - 1
            text: parent.text
            font.pointSize: parent.font.pointSize
            font.family: parent.font.family
            font.bold: parent.font.bold
            color: outlineColor
            z: -2
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: I developed the same solution too but, anyway, thank you for your time in develop this small example. I'm sure it will be useful for all future people looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, I wrote a `ShaderEffect` version.
But there are lots of other ways you can do it, including implementing your own `OpacityMask` if you don't want to use the Qt ones.

The shader is not very complex; it just inverts the color of the texture below it and draws a circle underneath.

> **NOTE**: You should either use `shader.frag` or `shader.glsl`.

###### preview:

[image]

###### TimePicker.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Control {
    id: control

    padding: font.pixelSize
    implicitWidth: 200
    implicitHeight: 200

    property alias model: repeater.model
    property real angle: 0
    property real ballRadius: 20
    property real radius: Math.min(availableWidth, availableHeight)/2;
    property vector2d center: Qt.vector2d(availableWidth/2, availableHeight/2)

    /// The shader that inverts color in the circle position.
    component InverterBall: ShaderEffectSource {
        id: shaderSource
        property color color

        recursive: false
        sourceRect: Qt.rect(x, y, width, height)
        layer.enabled: true
        layer.effect: ShaderEffect {
            property var source
            property size size: Qt.size(width, height)
            property color color: shaderSource.color

            fragmentShader: "qrc:/shader.glsl" // for Qt6 use `qrc:/shader.frag.qsb`
        }
    }

    background: Rectangle { radius: width }
    contentItem: Item {
        /// Hours or minutes ticks can also be replaced with an array (i.e., numbers in Roman format).
        Item {
            id: ticks
            width: parent.width; height: parent.height
            Repeater {
                id: repeater
                model: 12
                Label {
                    property vector2d pos: {
                        const a = (index + 1) * 6.283/repeater.count - 1.57;
                        return Qt.vector2d(Math.cos(a), Math.sin(a)).times(radius).plus(center);
                    }

                    x: pos.x - implicitWidth/2
                    y: pos.y - implicitHeight/2

                    text: index + 1
                }
            }
        }

        /// The clock handle.
        Rectangle {
            x: center.x; y: center.y
            width: control.radius; height: 1; radius: height
            color: palette.button
            transform: Rotation { angle: control.angle - 90; origin{y: 0.5}}
            transformOrigin: Qt.TopLeftCorner
        }

        InverterBall {
            property vector2d pos: {
                const a = angle * 0.01745 - 1.57
                return Qt.vector2d(Math.cos(a), Math.sin(a)).times(radius).plus(center);
            }
            x: pos.x - width/2; y: pos.y - width/2

            sourceItem: ticks
            width: ballRadius; height: width
            color: palette.button
        }
    }
}
```

###### shader.glsl (Qt 5)

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
    precision highp int;
#endif

varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
uniform highp sampler2D source;
uniform highp float qt_Opacity;
uniform highp vec2 size;
uniform highp vec4 color;

void main() {
    float m = min(size.x, size.y);
    vec2 uv = (qt_TexCoord0 - 0.5) * size/min(size.x, size.y);
    vec4 t = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0);
    float c = smoothstep(0.5/m, 0.0, length(uv) - 0.5 + 0.5/m);
    gl_FragColor = mix(color, 1.0 - t, t.a) * c * qt_Opacity;
}
```

###### shader.frag (Qt 6)

```c
#version 440

layout(location = 0) in vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform buf {
    mat4 qt_Matrix; float qt_Opacity; vec2 size; vec4 color;
};
layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D source;

void main() {
    float m = min(size.x, size.y);
    vec2 uv = (qt_TexCoord0 - 0.5) * size/min(size.x, size.y);
    vec4 t = texture(source, qt_TexCoord0);
    float c = smoothstep(0.5/m, 0.0, length(uv) - 0.5 + 0.5/m);
    fragColor = mix(color, 1.0 - t, t.a) * c * qt_Opacity;
}
```

###### usage example

```
TimePicker {
    PointHandler {
        property real snap: 360/12 // snap to hours
        onTranslationChanged: {
            const p = point.position
            const center = parent.center.plus(Qt.vector2d(1,1).times(parent.padding));
            const angle = Math.atan2(p.y - center.x, p.x - center.x) * 57.3 + 90;
            parent.angle = Math.round(angle / snap) * snap;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really thank you for this very complete example but I want to develop a pure QML component (a single .qml file) without any additional files. However I'm very interested in how shader language work. You seems expert in this, can you suggest me some web stie where I can start learn how develop shader code? Thank you

Comment: @Suppaman Hi, **1)** Currently, even the `OpacityMask` itself is using the ShaderEffect.
**2)** For learning resources, you can start with the website [The Book of Shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com).
**3)** Thank you, but I'm also not an expert in this topic. However, I can recommend [Inigo Quilez](https://iquilezles.org), who is an expert.
**4)** Additionally, you can directly put the `shader.glsl` code as a `string` in the `fragmentShader`. However, unfortunately, this is not possible after **Qt 6**, and it should be used in an external file.

Comment: Thank you for the link of the book, it's really interesting and well written

Comment: @Suppaman You're welcome. As for the answer, please let me know if there are any edits I should make. I don't see any other way to achieve this.

Comment: I just posted here the result of my work available for all. I used the OpacityMask solution.